# How can i add a popup to an already existing button?

Tags: html, django, dialog, popup

I have this delete button on my posts that when you click on it it deletes the post I wanted to add a html popup that I have on that button so that when someone clocks on delete it first shows the confirmation popup and then delete the post if they clicked on ok how can I achieve that?

Thanks

Where my delete button is

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top: 25px"></div>
    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">{{post.title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        {{ post.body|truncatewords_html:30 }}
        <hr>
        <p><img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" width="75" height="75"> Author: {{ post.author }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'detail' post.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-small" >Read More <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-three-dots" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M3 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3z"/>
          </svg></a>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" >Delete <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z"/>
            <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z"/>
          </svg></a>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My html popup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap Delete Confirmation Modal</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    }
    .modal-confirm {        
        color: #636363;
        width: 400px;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }
    .modal-confirm .modal-content {
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: none;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .modal-confirm .modal-header {
        border-bottom: none;   
        position: relative;
    }
    .modal-confirm h4 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 26px;
        margin: 30px 0 -10px;
    }
    .modal-confirm .close {
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        right: -2px;
    }
    .modal-confirm .modal-body {
        color: #999;
    }
    .modal-confirm .modal-footer {
        border: none;
        text-align: center;     
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 13px;
        padding: 10px 15px 25px;
    }
    .modal-confirm .modal-footer a {
        color: #999;
    }       
    .modal-confirm .icon-box {
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 50%;
        z-index: 9;
        text-align: center;
        border: 3px solid #f15e5e;
    }
    .modal-confirm .icon-box i {
        color: #f15e5e;
        font-size: 46px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 13px;
    }
    .modal-confirm .btn {
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: #60c7c1;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: all 0.4s;
        line-height: normal;
        min-width: 120px;
        border: none;
        min-height: 40px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        outline: none !important;
    }
    .modal-confirm .btn-info {
        background: #c1c1c1;
    }
    .modal-confirm .btn-info:hover, .modal-confirm .btn-info:focus {
        background: #a8a8a8;
    }
    .modal-confirm .btn-danger {
        background: #f15e5e;
    }
    .modal-confirm .btn-danger:hover, .modal-confirm .btn-danger:focus {
        background: #ee3535;
    }
    .trigger-btn {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 100px auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text-center">
    <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
    <a href="#myModal" class="trigger-btn" data-toggle="modal">Click to Open Confirm Modal</a>
</div>

<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="icon-box">
                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE5CD;</i>
                </div>              
                <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>  
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you really want to delete these records? This process cannot be undone.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add an id attribute to your delete button to make it easier to target it with JavaScript. For example, you can add id="deleteButton" to your delete button.
2. Add a JavaScript code to handle the click event of the delete button and show the confirmation modal.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#deleteButton').click(function(){
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
```

```html
<a href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" id="deleteButton">Delete <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z"/>
    <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z"/>
  </svg></a>
```

Comment: Should I put the name of my html file on that '#myModal' part? and what about the 'show'? should I leave it that way?

Comment: I believe you have a div called ``<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">`` . I have called the id ``"#myModal"`` to the script. You don't have to change anything for now as in your HTML the id is the same. and for "show", it is a class of bootstrap to allow to show the ``modals``. you dont need to anything about the "show" class